# Parabolic Pde with unkown boundary conditions

Tags: partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, parabolic-pde

I have the following parabolic partial differential equation:

\begin{equation}
 \frac{\partial^2 \phi}{\partial x^2} - \alpha \sin{x} \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial t} + \beta(\cos{x} - \gamma) \phi = 0
\end{equation}

where $\phi(x,t)$ is a scalar function defined in  $ \Omega \equiv [0,L_x]\times [0,L_t]$, $\alpha$,$\beta$ and $\gamma$ and complex numbers. The idea is to apply as boundary conditions:
\begin{equation}
   \phi(x,0) = \phi(x,L_t) = 0 \quad \text{and} \quad \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x}(0,t) = \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x}(0,t) = 0.
\end{equation}
Actually, I'm not fully convinced whether there exists a solution consistent with these boundaries, so do you have any idea how to check if they are ok? Is there a systematic way to prove such things, and if so, how would you do that?
I also tried to solve it analytically and numerically, but I had some issues in determining the correct boundary conditions.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: $\phi =0$ satisfies the equation and boundary conditions

Comment: Have you tried using the maximum principle to try obtain uniqueness?

Comment: Yes, I have, but I'm not super practical on it and I didn't manage to find anything useful.